# Shopware 6: bin/watch-storefront.sh does not show our custom theme

Tags: webpack, shopware

We are using the ManuTheme and bin/watch-storefront.sh. (Production template, for a customer shop)

But the site shown using the Webpack Proxy is looking very different from what we normally see.

One theory is that the theme's files are not beeing loaded?
Is this true? Is there additional work needed to load all the theme files when using `watch-storefront`?

In the Webpack output all Theme Modules are listed:

```
# Webpack Plugin Injector: Plugin "Storefront" injected as a new entry point
# Webpack Plugin Injector: Plugin "ExampleProductListing" injected as a new entry point
# Webpack Plugin Injector: Plugin "DmfManuTheme" injected as a new entry point
# Webpack Plugin Injector: Plugin "dev24PriceFilterRangeSlider" injected as a new entry point
```

But some CSS is just missing. We checked whether files cannot be loaded, but there are no errors in the network tab.

When we open the page normally (without the Webpack Proxy) there is

```
.main-newsletter {
    background: #cddd5d;
    color: #242424;
    padding-top: 1.5rem;
    padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
}
```

This comes from the theme. But when we open it via the webpack proxy, this is missing.

Is this maybe expected behavior? How can this be further debugged?

We also tried changing `bin/watch-storefront.sh`

```
npm --prefix vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/app/storefront/ run-script hot-proxy
```

to

```
npm --prefix vendor/store.shopware.com/dmfmanutheme/src/Resources/app/storefront run-script hot-proxy
```

But then it does not even start up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure all css files are referenced in the `base.scss`. The current version only loads the `base.scss` while older verisons did load all files.

Maybe your theme is not ready for version 6.4

See: https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/6.4.0.0/UPGRADE-6.4.md#changed-the-loading-of-storefront-scss-files-in-extensions

Comment: We where on 2.0.0 and in https://github.com/digitalmanufaktur/shopware6-manu-theme/blob/v2.0.0/src/Resources/app/storefront/src/scss/base.scss#L89 the layout/newsletter file is referenced. But when I updated the theme to the recent 2.0.2 it all seems to work.

Comment: Wondering what caused that from those changes: https://github.com/digitalmanufaktur/shopware6-manu-theme/compare/v2.0.0...v2.0.2